# Navbar not full width in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a navbar with 100% width in bootstrap but it's not working.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> WebsiteName </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `container-fluid` class outside.you have already added the `container` inside.  `container-fluid` has padding

Comment: I want to create a portfolio webpage. If I remove container-fluid, how will my web page be responsive?

Comment: you don't require container-fluid for navbar.put continer fluid for the rest of your content.or remove the padding of container-fluid  using css

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding in container-fluid, create class "custom-nav-container" to overwrite.

```
    <div class="container-fluid custom-nav-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> WebsiteName </a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

.custom-nav-container{
padding-left: 0px !important;
padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<div class="container-">
```

To

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Inside your  tag. Your problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**.container** has one fixed width for each screen size in bootstrap (xs,sm,md,lg). It is responsive; however, it is fixed based on screen size.  **.container-fluid** expands to fill the available width. If you use the container-fluid and resize the browser, you may notice the content inside it will adjust with every pixel to take the full available width.

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> WebsiteName </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```